# How to get the top five fastest ground speeds using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

So I have this data imported from excel and I want to be able find the top five fastest speeds. I tried using the aggregate function but what was returned was 0.

```
db.planes.aggregate({
    $group : {
        _id : "$msg_dummy",
        fastest : {$max : "$ground_speed"}
    }
})


{ "_id" : "MSG", "fastest" : "" }
```

and only one printed out. I need the top five. Here is some of the data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df16994"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 4, "flight_id" : 680, "aircraft_id" : "A1C8EB", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214224, "latitude" : "", "longitude" : 306, "altitude" : 133, "ground_speed" : -512, "heading" : "", "dummy1" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df16995"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 4, "flight_id" : 680, "aircraft_id" : "A1C8EB", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214223, "latitude" : "", "longitude" : 307, "altitude" : 133, "ground_speed" : -512, "heading" : "", "dummy1" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df16996"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 1, "flight_id" : 680, "aircraft_id" : "A1C8EB", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214223, "latitude" : "", "longitude" : "", "altitude" : "", "ground_speed" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df16997"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 4, "flight_id" : 680, "aircraft_id" : "A1C8EB", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214223, "latitude" : "", "longitude" : 307, "altitude" : 133, "ground_speed" : -512, "heading" : "", "dummy1" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df16998"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 1, "flight_id" : "AAL1538", "aircraft_id" : "ABFEFD", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214224, "latitude" : "", "longitude" : "", "altitude" : "", "ground_speed" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df16999"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 4, "flight_id" : "AAL1538", "aircraft_id" : "ABFEFD", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214224, "latitude" : "", "longitude" : 298, "altitude" : 123, "ground_speed" : 64, "heading" : "", "dummy1" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df1699a"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 4, "flight_id" : 680, "aircraft_id" : "A1C8EB", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214224, "latitude" : "", "longitude" : 306, "altitude" : 133, "ground_speed" : -512, "heading" : "", "dummy1" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df1699b"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 1, "flight_id" : "NKS355", "aircraft_id" : "A67CA6", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214225, "latitude" : "", "longitude" : "", "altitude" : "", "ground_speed" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df1699c"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 3, "flight_id" : 680, "aircraft_id" : "A1C8EB", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214225, "latitude" : 28.64559, "longitude" : -81.57871, "altitude" : 10100, "ground_speed" : 306, "heading" : 133, "dummy1" : -512, "dummy2" : "", "field13" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df1699d"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 3, "flight_id" : 680, "aircraft_id" : "A1C8EB", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214225, "latitude" : 28.64517, "longitude" : -81.57823, "altitude" : 10100, "ground_speed" : 306, "heading" : 133, "dummy1" : -512, "dummy2" : "", "field13" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58076dffa85331269df1699e"), "msg_dummy" : "MSG", "msg_type" : 4, "flight_id" : "AAL1538", "aircraft_id" : "ABFEFD", "date" : 20131213, "time" : 214225, "latitude" : "", "longitude" : 298, "altitude" : 123, "ground_speed" : 64, "heading" : "", "dummy1" : "" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `ground_speed` field has a mixture of numerical and string values (empty string), the **[`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/)** operator returns the maximum value since it compares both value and type using the [specified BSON comparison order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types-comparison-order) for values of different types.

You need to filter the documents and compare only the ones with numerical values for `ground_speed`:

```
db.planes.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "ground_speed": { "$exists": true, "$type": 1 }  
    } },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$msg_dummy",
            "fastest" : { "$max" : "$ground_speed"}
        }
    }
])
```

---

To answer your question, getting the top 5 speeds requires ordering the documents by the `ground_speed` field using the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline, creating an array with the `ground_speed` values within the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline using the accumulator operator **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** and then returning the top 5 from the array using a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline and the **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)** operator.

The following example shows this:

```
db.planes.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "ground_speed": { "$exists": true, "$type": 1 }  
    } },
    { "$sort": { "ground_speed": -1 } },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$msg_dummy",
            "ground_speeds" : { "$push" : "$ground_speed" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "msg_dummy": "$_id",
            "top_five_fastest": { "$slice": ["$ground_speeds", 5] },
            "ground_speeds": 1
        }
    }
])
```

---

For MongoDB versions which do not support the **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)** operator, as an alternative you can get the top 5 by limiting the number of documents getting into the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline using the **[`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit)** operator and this should be placed after the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline (on ordered documents):

```
db.planes.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "ground_speed": { "$exists": true, "$type": 1 }  
    } },
    { "$sort": { "ground_speed": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 5 },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$msg_dummy",
            "top_five_fastest" : { "$push" : "$ground_speed" }
        }
    }   
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using an aggregate query.

Try the following:

```
 db.planes.find({},{_id:1,ground_speed:1}).sort({ground_speed:-1}).limit(5)
```

Comment: Thanks so much this helped a lot

Comment: You're welcome. If you're happy with the answer can you accept it please?